# Problemas al asignar el valor de una variable PHP a un atributo id de un div en html

Tags: php, html, backend

Hola alguien que me ayude o oriente, tengo problemas al asignar el valor de una variable php a un atributo id de un div en HTML, he estado intentando pero no me genera el id dinámico de cada div ala hora de hacer el ciclo while con php, dicho ciclo me ayuda a extraer los valores de mi variable para mostrarlos en la interfaz de usuario en cada vuela pretendo asignar el valor que según trae gua mi variable php pero hasta el momento no he logrado, ya he intentado de diversas formas. el problema es que quiero asignar el nombre de la categoría del producto como un id en el atributo de un div de html para que me abra cada acordeón cuando lo presione según su id dinámico este es el atributo de el div data-target al cual le asigno lo que tengo en el nombre de mi categoria y a el id de el acordeon que quiero abriri le asigno el mismo valor de la variable php para que coincidan los id:

```
<div id="accordion">

  <?php while($categ=$catego->fetch_object()):?>


    <div class="card mb-2">
      <div class="card-header text-center collapsed " id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?=$categ->catego_categoria;?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <a class="btn texto-categoria" >
            <?=$categ->catego_categoria;?>
          </a>
        </h5>
      </div>

      <div id="<?=$categ->catego_categoria;?>" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
        <div class="card-body">
          <div class="row">
          <!-- incio card -->
          <?php $prod=Utils::showProducts($categ->catego_id); ?>
          <?php while($product=$prod->fetch_object()): ?>
          <div class="card col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3 " style="width: 18rem;">
              <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=base_url?>uploads/images_product/<?=$product->foto;?>" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title"><?=$product->prod_nombre;?></h5>
              <h6 class="card-text">$ <?=$product->prod_precio;?> mxn.</h6>
                  <h6 class="card-text">codigo:<?=$product->prod_clave;?></h6>
              <p class="card-text"><?=$product->prod_descripcion;?></p>
              <a href="<?=base_url?>Producto/detalle_producto&id=<?=$product->prod_id;?>" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
          <!-- fin card -->

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  <?php endwhile; ?>


  </div>
```

Espero me puedan orientar gracias y saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que indicar al navegador que muestre la información mediante el echo.

Te lo he corregido. Prueba y me dices:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <?php while($categ=$catego->fetch_object()):?>
        <div class="card mb-2">
            <div class="card-header text-center collapsed " id="headingOne" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#<?php echo $categ->catego_categoria; ?>" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                <h5 class="mb-0">
                    <a class="btn texto-categoria" >
                        <?php echo $categ->catego_categoria; ?>
                    </a>
                </h5>
            </div>

            <div id="<?php echo $categ->catego_categoria; ?>" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                        <!-- incio card -->
                        <?php $prod=Utils::showProducts($categ->catego_id); ?>
                        <?php while($product=$prod->fetch_object()): ?>
                            <div class="card col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4 my-3 " style="width: 18rem;">
                                <img class="card-img-top" src="<?php echo base_url; ?>uploads/images_product/<?php echo $product->foto; ?>" alt="Card image cap">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $product->prod_nombre; ?></h5>
                                    <h6 class="card-text"><?php echo $product->prod_precio; ?> mxn.</h6>
                                    <h6 class="card-text">codigo:<?php echo $product->prod_clave; ?></h6>
                                    <p class="card-text"><?php echo $product->prod_descripcion; ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?=base_url?>Producto/detalle_producto&id=<?php echo $product->prod_id; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        <?php endwhile; ?>
                <!-- fin card -->
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

PD: Aprende a tabular bien el código, será mucho mejor para ti y para los que lo leen ;)

Comment: Gracias saludos si me sirvió era eso